# why is my sort function(sorting by exchanging data) in linked list not working

Tags: c++, sorting

when i run this function it returns all the numbers as it is without sorting anything?It works perfectly fine when i use for loop?Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
struct node //structure node 
{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};

void sort(struct node *start)       //function for sorting
{
    struct node *p,*temp;
    int r;
    p = start;
    temp = p->link;
    while(p != NULL)      //first loop
    {
        while(temp != NULL)    //second loop
        {
            if(temp->info < p->info)
            {
                r=p->info;
                p->info = temp->info;
                temp->info = r;
            }
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        p = p->link;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: Also, you only loop the inner `while` loop for one iteration of the outer. `temp` doesn't get set in the outer `while` loop.

Comment: I edited your code to include indenting and whitespace to improve the readability (especially when using a lot of arrow (`->`) operators

Comment: Use this opportunity to get familiar with your debugger.  Confirm what you see in the answers below with your debugger so that in the future you will know how to find these errors yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are moving the temp pointer in the inner loop till it reaches `NULL`, but you are not setting it back to `temp = p->link;` in the outer loop;

Please add `temp = p->link;` just after

```
while(p != NULL)      //first loop
    {
```

**Updated function should look like this :**

```
void sort(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *p,*temp;
    int r;
    p = start;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        temp = p->link;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            if(temp->info < p->info)
            {
                r=p->info;
                p->info = temp->info;
                temp->info = r;
            }
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        p = p->link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After your first iteration of the outer `while` loop, `temp` will be `NULL`. However, `temp` isn't set outside of the inner `while` loop, therefore it will stay `NULL`. The numbers only will change if `start->info` wasn't the smallest one.

Move the assignment `temp = p->link` *into* the outer while loop instead:

```
void sort(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *p,*temp;
    int r;
    p = start;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        temp = p->link;        // <-------
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            if(temp->info < p->info)
            {
                r=p->info;
                p->info = temp->info;
                temp->info = r;
            }
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        p = p->link;
    }
}
```